# Implement " xml-elements" using MOXy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I want to know how to implement having List of interface Type using EclipseLink MOXy, 
Before, using JAXB , The following annotations did the job

```
class A {

   @XmlElements({
       @XmlElement(name = "B1", type = B1.class),
       @XmlElement(name = "B2", type = B2.class)
    })
    List< B > list;

}

interface B{}

class B1 implements B {}

class B2 implements B {}
```

to support List of interface type ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I lead [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  I am not able to reproduce your issue.  Could you provide the stack trace you are seeing?  The following is what I have tried:

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.Version;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Version.getVersionString());

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class, B1.class, B2.class);
        System.out.println(jc);

        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<A> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xml), A.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <B1/>
   <B2/>
</root>
```

**Output**

```
2.2.0.v20110202-r8913
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext@11ddcde
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <B1/>
   <B2/>
</root>
```

---

**Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)'s XML Metadata File**

MOXy also has an extension to provide the metadata as an XML file.  Below is what it would look like for this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="com.example">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="A">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-elements java-attribute="list">
                    <xml-element name="B1" type="com.example.B1"/>
                    <xml-element name="B2" type="com.example.B2"/>
                </xml-elements>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

This metadata file is passed in as a property when the JAXBContext is created:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, new File("src/forum149/bindings.xml"));
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {A.class, B1.class, B2.class}, properties);
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: In the example provided above I was able to marshal / unmarshal object that contains List of Interface type by using XmlElements annotations. But I  don’t know how to create a binding XML that can do the same thing.
I am trying to use MoXy's mapping file instead of using annotations (like binding.xml mentioned here http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html) .  Suppose that PhoneNumber class is an interface that has two implementing classes (ex: XPhoneNumber, YPhoneNumber) how this is going to be described in the binding xml?

Comment: @RO86 - I have updated my answer to include the MOXy mapping file.  It assumes the model classes are in the "com.example" package.